# How to extract text string from a CTlineRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-text, ctlineref

How to extract text string from a CTlineRef ?

i know for example that i can do CTLineGetStringRange(aLine) and i have the AttributedString (ie: CFAttributedStringRef) that was used to generate the line. how to extract the text string from the AttributedString  ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you CTLineGetGlyphRuns... then CTRunGetGlyphs... from each run.

Comment: thank john, but CTRunGetGlyphs will return me CGGlyph... i want to retrieve a CFStringRef :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have this:

```
CFAttributedStringRef cfAttributedString = ...;
CTLineRef line = ...;
CFRange cfRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line);
```

Convert the `CFRange` to an `NSRange` and cast the `CFAttributedStringRef` to an `NSAttributedString *`:

```
NSRange nsRange = NSMakeRange(cfRange.location, cfRange.length);
NSAttributedString *richText = (__bridge NSAttributedString *)cfAttributedString;
```

Then you can use an Objective-C message to get the substring. If you want an attributed substring:

```
NSAttributedString *richSubtext = [richText attributedSubstringFromRange:nsRange];
```

If you want a plain substring:

```
NSString *substring = [richText.string substringWithRange:nsRange];
```

If you want to stick with Core Foundation functions for some reason (I wouldn't recommend it), you can get the attributed substring:

```
CFAttributedStringRef cfAttributedSubstring = CFAttributedStringCreateWithSubstring(
    NULL, cfAttributedString, cfRange);
```

Or the plain substring like this:

```
CFStringRef cfString = CFAttributedStringGetString(cfAttributedString);
CFStringRef cfSubstring = CFStringCreateWithSubstring(NULL, cfString, cfRange);
```